# Which combinations between features with a polynomial degree less than or equal to a specified polynomial degree count as polynomial combinations?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

There is a feature matrix X with 2 features. The following Code prints all polynomial combinations of the features with degree less than or equal to 3.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

X = np.ones((3,2))
pf = PolynomialFeatures(3)
pf.fit(X)
print(pf.get_feature_names())

['1', 'x0', 'x1', 'x0^2', 'x0 x1', 'x1^2', 'x0^3', 'x0^2 x1', 'x0 x1^2', 'x1^3']
```

Which rule is used to decide which combinations between features count as polynomial combinations?

Why do for example the combinations x0^3 x1, x0^3 x1^2 or even x0^2 x1^2 not count as polynomial combinations?

Comment: Those are polynomial combinations but their degrees are not less than or equal to 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basic algebra. The examples you are showing dont have degree 3.

For two variables, the power of each term in the polynomial is the sum of the exponents in each term and the degree of the polynomial is the largest such sum.

For your examples:

```
x0^3 x1     Degree = 4
x0^3 x1^2   Degree = 5
x0^2 x1^2   Degree = 4
```

Please look at the following resources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial
- http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/Polynomials.aspx

Comment: Makes sense to me. Thanks!